# VBA saved files crashes when printing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that formats and saves multiple versions of a report, but whenever I try to print one of the saved version excel crashes.

There are no named ranges or formulas in the saved version, and the sub seems to run successfully, so I can't understand why excel won't let me print. Strangely opening and saving a new version of the reports will let me print, even with nothing changing.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: If you need help with your code, please include it in your topic.

Comment: This [article](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/121317-office-2010-crashes-when-printing) might help

Comment: Can you post your code ? How are you saving multiple copies, and in what format ? Is the file that you want to print open ?